# Jenkins Pipeline - unable to curl send message to MSTeams Webhook

Tags: jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

any suggestion on how can I successfully send a message to MSTeams via webhook using curl?
I have tried this approach however it failed

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Start Deployment') {
      steps {
          sh """#!/bin/bash +x
            echo ${BUILD_URL}console
            curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"Jenkins Started to deploy = ${BUILD_URL}console\"}" https://outlook.office.com/webhook/pogi-panget-dungul-bungul-maohab/IncomingWebhook/pogipangetdungulmaohab/pogi-panget-dungul-bungul-maohab
          """

      }

    }

  }
}
```

Getting this error

```
Started by user Ako, Lagot
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on EC2 (SERVER) - SERVER (i-9002893989sds1) in /home/ec2-user/workspace/TEST-JOB
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Check Instance Type)
[Pipeline] sh
https://lagot-ka-sakin-testserver.net/job/TEST-JOB/11/console
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Started

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: to

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: deploy
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: =
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 79

100    63  100    49  100    14    194     55 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   249
Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I also tested that this curl command was able to send message to MSTeams webhook using jenkins Freestayle job. However getting this issue when testing it to Pipeline as specifi

Comment: Suggest you use `-d '{"text": "Jenkins ... "}'`

Comment: Thanks MaratC I also found an alternative way yo fix too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this myself by replacing the double quotes " to single quote '

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"text\": \"Jenkins Started to deploy = ${BUILD_URL}console\"}' https://outlook.office.com/webhook/pogi-panget-dungul-bungul-maohab/IncomingWebhook/pogipangetdungulmaohab/pogi-panget-dungul-bungul-maohab
```